# Let (X, Y ) have bivariate normal density $f(x, y) = \frac{\sqrt{ab−c^2}}{2π}e^{− \frac{1}{2}(ax^2+by^2+2cxy)}$, find marginal distribution of Y.

Tags: probability, probability-theory, probability-distributions, normal-distribution, conditional-probability

Let (X, Y ) have bivariate normal density $f(x, y) = \frac{\sqrt{ab−c^2}}{2π}e^{− \frac{1}{2}(ax^2+by^2+2cxy)}$, how can i calculate marginal distribution of Y from the joint pdf. I know we have to integrate joint pdf $wrt$ x, but i am not able to do it.

Answer (score 0):

Hint:
\begin{align}
&\exp(-ax^2 + by^2+2cyx) = \exp(\frac{c^2y^2}{a})\times \exp(-(\sqrt ax^2 + \frac{2cy\sqrt{a}x}{\sqrt{a}} + \frac{c^2y^2}{a}))\\
&=\exp(\frac{c^2y^2}{a})\times \exp\bigg(-\bigg(\sqrt{a}x+\frac{cy}{\sqrt{a}}\bigg)^2\bigg)
\end{align}